# Is there a way to make Java graphic shapes interact with each other?

Tags: java, graphics

```
private void moveBall(){



    if (balldown==true){
        y++; 

    }


    if (balldown==false){
        y--;

    }

    if(y==getHeight()-border){


        balldown=false;
        bounce++;
    }
    if(y==0){


        balldown=true;
        bounce++;
    }

    if (ballright==true){
        x++;          
    }

    if (ballright==false){
        x--;

    }

    if(x==getWidth()){


        ballright=false;
        bounce++;
    }
    if(x==0){


        ballright=true;
        bounce++;

    }



}

public void paint(Graphics g){


    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 1080, 760);


    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, a, 30, 200);

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(980, b, 30, 200);

    g.fillRect(520, 0, 10, 760);
```

Im a java beginner
Is there a way to make my ball bounce off the graphic rectangles the same way it bounces off the window edges?If I add the width or height measures to an if statements it just treats it as the whole screens so I am at a loss on how to solve this issue.Is there some sort of way to tread only the rectangle part as a screen edge instead of the whole side?

Comment: It's difficult when you don't know what to search for. Here the term is "collision detection". And you might want to look for the term "sprite".

Comment: Thank you for the useful input. You are right, I was looking for the wrong thing. Sadly my colision still does not work but atleast now I know what to ask. How to I mark this post as solved ? :D